# repartitionByCassandraReplica - partitionsPerHost

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

So, I have a 16 node cluster where every node has Spark and Cassandra installed with a replication factor of 3 and spark.sql.shuffle.partitions of 96 and Spark-Cassandra-Connector 3.1.0.

I am trying to repartitionByCassandraReplica().JoinWithCassandraTable() on partition keys of a RDD with a cassandra table. The size of the data of the cassandra table that will be joined is 84Gb and I would like to know what would be the ideal number of partitionsPerHost. How should I calculate that? Let me know if you need any more information on my cluster.